# |Python| Find Parents from Tree Methode doesn't word (EN/DE)

Tags: python, tree, parent

I have the following tree and function from a class:

```
├── A
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── D
│   │   └── E
│   └── C
│       ├── F
│       └── D
├── E
└── F

def find_parents(self, target_val, parents=None):
        if self.val == target_val:
            return parents
        if parents is None:
            parents = []
        for child in self.children:
            result = child.find_parents(target_val, parents + [self.val])
            if result is not None:
                return result
        return None
```

I want the parents of the input to be output. If I enter E I get ['A', 'B'], if I enter F I get ['A', 'C']. This is all correct so far. But if I now enter D I get ['A', 'B'] and that is wrong, because the parents of D are -> B & C . What do I have to change in my function to make it work?

I asked ChatGPT and he can't help me

Comment: What is the exact output you expect for `D`? Is it `[['A','B'],['A','C']]` or `['A',['B','C']]` or `['B','C']` or .... something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives you all ancestors of the first instance, not the immediate parent of all (duplicate) instances.

I can't test it without a reproductible example, but it should look something like this:

```
def find_parents(self, target_val,parent=None):
    result = []
    if self.val == target_val and parent:
        result.append(parent.val)
    for child in self.children:
        result.extend(child.find_parent(target_val,self))
    return result
```

Comment: I uploaded a new Question, with the whole code

Comment: Thank you Broter, it worked. Love you<3