# How do I fix the tree traversal in my find_parents method?

Tags: python, tree, parent

I have the following tree and the function `find_parents()` from my class:

```
├── A
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── D
│   │   └── E
│   └── C
│       ├── F
│       └── D
├── E
└── F
```

```
class Knoten:
    def __init__(self, wert):
        self.val = wert
        self.children = []

    # Fügt die Kindestknoten zu einem Vaterknoten hinzu
    def add_knoten(self, add_knoten):
        self.children.append(add_knoten)

    # Gibt die Struktur des Baumes aus
    def StrukturOutput(self, ebene=0):
        einruecken = " " * ebene
        print(einruecken + self.val)
        for i in self.children:
            i.StrukturOutput(ebene + 1)

   def get_leaf_nodes(self, target_val):
        if self.val == target_val:
            if len(self.children) == 0:
                return [self.val]
            else:
                leaf_nodes = []
                for child in self.children:
                    if len(child.children) == 1:  # Überprüfung, ob der Kindknoten Blattknoten ist
                        leaf_nodes.append(child.val)
                    leaf_nodes.extend(child.get_leaf_nodes(child.val))
                return leaf_nodes
        else:
            for child in self.children:
                leaf_nodes = child.get_leaf_nodes(target_val)
                if leaf_nodes:
                    return leaf_nodes
        return []

   # Gibt den Vater eines Knoten aus
    def find_parents(self, target_val, parents=None):
        if self.val == target_val:
            return parents
        if parents is None:
            parents = []
        for child in self.children:
            result = child.find_parents(target_val, parents + [self.val])
            if result is not None:
                return result
        return None
            

# Erstellt die Wurzel
baum = Knoten('A')

# Erstelleung der Kindenknoten, der Wurzel
b = Knoten('B')
c = Knoten('C')
e = Knoten('E')
f = Knoten('F')

# Erstellt die Kinderknoten des Knoten B
b1 = Knoten("D")
b2 = Knoten("E")
# Erstellt die Beziehung zwischen B und seinen Kinderknoten
b.add_knoten(b1)
b.add_knoten(b2)

# Erstellt die Kinderknoten des Knoten B
c1 = Knoten("F")
c2 = Knoten("D")
# Erstellt die Beziehung zwischen B und seinen Kinderknoten
c.add_knoten(c1)
c.add_knoten(c2)

# Beziehung zwischen Wurzel und seinen Kindern
baum.add_knoten(b)
baum.add_knoten(c)
baum.add_knoten(e)
baum.add_knoten(f)


suche = input("Insert (Tree nodes): ")

if baum.get_leaf_nodes(suche) == [suche]:
    vater = baum.find_parents(suche)
    if vater:
        print(f"Vaterknoten von {suche} sind {vater}")
else:
    kinder = baum.get_leaf_nodes(suche)
    print(f"{suche} hat folgende Kinder: {kinder}")
```

I want the parents of the input to be output. If I enter E I get ['A', 'B'], if I enter F I get ['A', 'C']. This is all correct so far. But if I now enter D I get ['A', 'B'] and that is wrong, because the parents of D are -> B & C . What do I have to change in my function to make it work?

Comment: You asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76397526/python-find-parents-from-tree-methode-doesnt-word-en-de). Please, instead edit that question, and respond to the comment and answer you got there instead of posting it again.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

is in the for loop, so lets disassemble it quickly (looking at it almost line per line, not everything is properly indented):

```py
for child in self.children:
```

Iterating over all children of a node -- fine.

```py
result = child.find_parents(target_val, parents + [self.val])
```

finds all the children nodes of a node -- fine, but here the problem begins with `parents + [self.val]`.
For the input `D`: this would generate the following parent list: `['A', 'B']`.
This seems wrong, as you don't want to include grandparents, only the immediately parents. But it's fine if the next lines would look different:

```py
if result is not None:
    return result
```

This return is too early. A has multiple children: B and C. But because the result for B would be not None (because it found a D), your algorithm returns and doesn't continue looking down other paths (for D it wouldn't consider checking the C node).
At this point `parents` is just the first path through the tree to some element you search for (This means your tested results for E and F are only accidentally correct)

### The solution:

```py
def find_parents(self, target_val, parents=None):
        if self.val == target_val:
            return parents
        if parents is None:
            parents = []
        current_node_parents = []
        for child in self.children:
            result = child.find_parents(target_val, parents + [self.val])
            if result:
                current_node_parents.append(result[-1])
        return current_node_parrents
```

This solution constructs the path as your code did before, but instead of just returning it, it gets the immediate parent of the nodes with the value you look for (through adding the last node in the path which is equivalent to the parent).

Also, it returns the result at the end of the function which avoids the early return (not checking all paths).

This new code gives the following results(excerpt):

```
D => ['B', 'C']
E => ['B', 'A']
F => ['C', 'A']
```